# Printing duplex on Linux Mint

Tags: kde, printing, cups, samsung

I'm trying to print duplex on my new Samsung Xpress M2625D. I installed the driver from the Samsung website and changed the driver setting to duplex.

When I print a test page using the button in the driver, the printer prints in duplex like it is supposed to. The same goes for libre writer. However, if I print in Firefox or Evince the printer prints simplex.

I'm using Mint Linux and KDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't done in the driversettings, but the program you print in. I've had good experience with evince and chrome